# Can't attach android app to device from intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-2.3, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04(64bit) and intelliJ 11.1.2 and Android SDK (2.3.3 with google api) and when I try to run my app on a real device from intelliJ it won't run it. Actually I can see my device in running device dialog box but I only get following error:

```
06-24 22:02:10.370: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12081): GC_EXPLICIT freed 204K, 38% free 5743K/9223K, external 0K/512K, paused 79ms
06-24 22:03:24.372: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14169): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-24 22:03:24.372: INFO/AndroidRuntime(14169): Heap size: -Xmx32m
06-24 22:03:24.372: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14169): CheckJNI is OFF
06-24 22:03:24.372: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14169): creating instr width table
06-24 22:03:24.603: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14169): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-24 22:03:24.663: DEBUG/dalvikvm(13730): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 51% free 2686K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 31ms
06-24 22:03:24.663: WARN/ActivityManager(172): No content provider found for:
06-24 22:03:24.673: DEBUG/PackageParser(172): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-795727220.tmp
06-24 22:03:24.673: WARN/ActivityManager(172): No content provider found for:
06-24 22:03:24.793: DEBUG/dalvikvm(172): GC_EXPLICIT freed 361K, 56% free 5933K/13255K, external 35K/547K, paused 82ms
06-24 22:03:24.823: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14169): Shutting down VM
06-24 22:03:24.823: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 215K, 71% free 306K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+0ms
```

but in other side I can run the same application using eclipse with the same android sdk configuration.

I think something is not fine with intelliJ or I mis-config something on intelliJ

my java SDK :
open-java-amd64 1.6
sun-java-1.6 32bit

Comment: The log is not very informative. Maybe you can share a sample project to reproduce it?

Comment: Have you added your device into a list of allowed devices? You have to do this on Ubuntu